# Correct Android layout for this design

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to build the following layout, but am unsure which android layout I should be using.

[image: My layout]

Its just a table (correct terminology?), but I would like functionality such as swipe to delete a row, and to expand on click (to reveal another view).  It should also be scrollable.

What I have currently is a `LinearLayout` on a scroll view, which I populate with other custom layouts.

To achieve the expanding functionality, I have more custom views in the LinearLayout which are hidden by default, and then revealed if they layout above them is pressed.  All of this lives in a `ScrollView`.

---

Would a `TableLayout` be better for all of this?  I originally picked LinearLayout instead of TableLayout because I was confused about the TableLayout columns (and didn't need multiple columns).  I feel like right now I am reinventing the wheel.

Comment: If you want to scroll through the individual items, you'll want to be using a list view as the scrollable container.  List views perform some recycling on inflated list items so that flinging up and down a long list takes substantially less memory.

The list items themselves can be whatever makes sense for the data they need to hold.  Linear Layout is reasonable, though any complex arrangement is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need **ScrollView** or **TableLayout** at all. The easy way is to use a `ListView`, then on the raw adapter, you implement an `onTouchListener` method with swipe gesture algorithme (not hard to code).

But the *swipe* and *expandable* view can be handle with this library (very usefull)

https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

Comment: Wow.  I can't believe I didn't consider a `ListView`.  I guess I was only considering layouts and not views.  Thanks!